# Ajax web service - do not work in public address

Tags: ajax, web-services, spring-mvc, proxy

I have server with tomcat where I deployed my application.
Let's call that server: internalServer (it can be accessed only from my network)

System admin opened port so every request from public can access that application. Application is comunicating with some another application on same server via web services.

When I access application via:
internalServer:8080/application
everything works.
But , when I access application via:
mywebsite.com/application
everything works except calling web service via $.ajax

Does anyone have idea what could be problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a permissions issue with the public web site.  The trust factor when using a localhost-style web server is different from that of using a public server.  Check the web server and see what the permissions settings are for the directory where your web service is located.
Just a thought...

Comment: Thanks, that was problem